# How to use Pretty table with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, prettytable

I am programming my first website with flask one of my sections is a list of all sub-users for the teacher's class so how can I use prettytable with flask to get a table my end goal is a table that looks like this (just the data)

```
        Teacher | Student          |    Id    | GPA | Last sign learned 
        ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Medina  | John doe         | 19500688 | 4.0 | Bad
        Medina  | Samantha babcock | 91234094 | 2.5 | Toilet
        Jonson  | Steven smith     | 64721881 | 3.0 | Santa
```

How can I do this preferably with Pretty table but any method would be great!

Comment: Why not use get_html_string() provided by prettytable, save it in a variable and create your view with it. See: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: Because I cannot seem to `get the get_html_string` function to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello so your form is simple to create but so lets begin with static information with python

```
 def function():            
            from prettytable import *
            table = PrettyTable(["Teacher","Student"," ID","GPA"," Last sign learned "])
            table.add_row(["Medina","John doe","19500688","4.0","Bad"])
            table.add_row(["Medina","Samantha babcock ","91234094","2.5","Toilet"])
            table.add_row(["Jonson","Steven smith","64721881","3.0","Santa"])
            return render_template("info.html", tbl=table.get_html_string(attributes = {"class": "foo"}))
```

Now for you HTML:

```
{%extends "template.html"%}
    {{tbl|safe}}
```